# Is there anyway to bypass, get around, or avoid Kasada Bot Mitigation protection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I'm creating a software that basically logs into nike using your account and it will navigate to your most recent order, scrape that info, and send it back to a discord webhook. Nike seems to use both Akamai and Kasdada and I managed to find a work around to get through Akamai, but unfortunately can't get passed Kasada. I get the error "Error parsing server" Which is Kasada detecting you using some form of automation and blocking you. I have tried a handful of things such as headless browser, using a proxy, disable the automation blink feature, but it all seems futile. I'm a beginner at best when it comes to web scrapping so go easy on me. I'm using NodeJS and Puppeteer to create this program. Below is my current code and where it breaks at. "Ignore my comments"

````
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });
const fs = require("fs");
const { Webhook, MessageBuilder } = require("discord-webhook-node");

const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

/* const proxy = '208.194.232.77:8080';
const username = '3cw7073bgg';
const password = '2c0309ffc2'; */

( async () => {

    // Established Initial Browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false, // false = Shows Browser | true = Browser Not Shown
        executablePath: `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`,
        userDataDir: `/Users/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
        args: [
            // `--proxy-server=${proxy}`, //
            `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`,
            `--enable-blink-feautres=IdleDetection`
        ]
     });

     // Required Inputs The User Needs To Enter
         /*let webhookURL = prompt("What is your discord webhook? ");*/
         let accountEmail = prompt("What is your email address? ");
         let accountPassword = prompt("What is your account password? ");

     // Opens New Tab
    const page = await browser.newPage(); // Opens up a new tab within the browser


    // Stores Cookies To Local Storage To Reuse
     /* const saveCookie = async (page) => {
        const cookies = await page.cookies();
        const cookieJson = JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2);
        await fs.writeFile('cookies.json', cookieJson)
     }

    
    // Loads The Cookies Stored
    const loadCookie = async (page) => {
        const cookieJson = await fs.readFile('cookies.json');
        const cookies = JSON.parse(cookieJson);
        await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    } */

    // Browser Variables & Properties
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // This can be set true or false or completely removed. Haven't really noticed anything
    await page.setCacheEnabled(true);
    await page.setBypassCSP(true);
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 }); // Browser Size
   //  await page.authenticate({ username, password }); // This calls from the proxy data above to use to login into proxy
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000); 
    await page.goto("https://www.nike.com/"); // This is where you input the site that you want the script to open
        console.log('Browser has successfully opened!');

        // ---------------- Login Process ----------------  //

     // Navigates To The Login Page
        await page.waitForSelector('.nav-btn.p0-sm.d-sm-b.body-4.u-bold.ml2-sm.mr2-sm');
        await page.click('.nav-btn.p0-sm.d-sm-b.body-4.u-bold.ml2-sm.mr2-sm');
            console.log("Navigating To Login Page...")


    // Inputs Account Email
    await page.waitForSelector('#username');
    await page.click("#username", { delay: 500 });
        console.log("Typing Email Address...");
    await page.keyboard.type(`${accountEmail}`, { delay: 750 });
        console.log('Account Email Entered!');
    await page.waitForSelector('.css-14l6ovh.btn-primary-dark.btn-lg')
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter", { delay: 30000 });``` <= It breaks here after waiting for server response.
````

Answer (score 0):

Professional anti-bot services use countermeasures against Puppeteer, including plugins like stealth/extra-stealth. It's unlikely that you will be successful using the stuff that is "out there", unfortunately.

Akamai is lax compared to Kasada, that's why you apparently have been successful.

Either way, I wish you the best. You will have to do *the work* to bypass it. Not impossible, but challenging!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this solution on the substack linked on the previous answer.

```html
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


CHROMIUM_ARGS= [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled'
      ]
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_data_dir='./userdata/', channel="chrome", headless=False,slow_mo=200, args=CHROMIUM_ARGS,ignore_default_args=["--enable-automation"])
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.canadagoose.com/us/en/home-page', timeout=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    page.screenshot(path="pl_kasada.png")
```

With this solution I was able to bypass the block on the homepage on this target website.

ignore_default_args=["--enable-automation"] is needed to disable the infobar with the “Chrome is controlled by an automated test service” message.

'--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled' is needed to set correctly to null the AutomationControlled property of the browser.